# sed: search and replace string with line number

Tags: string, replace, sed, numbers, line

I have a XML file with a lot of empty tag attributes. For instance:

```
<mytag id="">
  <ontent>aaa</content>
</mytag>
<mytag id="">
  <ontent>bbb</content>
</mytag>
<mytag id="">
  <ontent>ccc</content>
</mytag>
```

Now I want to replace id="" with e.g. id="2443" (id="[linenumber]")

I tried to do this with sed, but I did not get a successful result.

I hope someone here can help me :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace empty `id=""` with `id="l"` where `l` is the line number where the `mytag` is found you can do:

**Edit:**

Based on the comments:

```
perl -pe '$i++; s{id=""}{id="$i"}' < file.xml
```

Comment: This will work provided that the XML input is not free-form but exactly as posted. Nit-pick: you can drop the `print` if you use `perl -pe` instead.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this would be better done with perl -ne /here be code/ < filename - for speeds sake, but otherwise spot on.

Comment: I dig the braces on the `s` operator. I always forget you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that your XML - which can be free-form - is in the exact form you wrote, awk or perl could do the job far more simply than sed. Unicornaddict had something that will work, but I'd be a little more careful in the substitution line:

```
perl -pe '$i++; s{id=""}{id="$i"} if /^<mytag id="">/' filename.xml
```

If you can't guarantee that the XML is not free-form, you'd really have to parse it with a proper XML parser. Generalized XML cannot be parsed with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try with `awk` instead. The line number is stored in `NR` variable.